# Does POSIX sh allow empty compound-list in first condition and empty condition in case conditional construct?

Tags: shell, posix

Reading [POSIX specification for case conditional construct](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04_05), I see:

```
case word in
    [(]pattern1) compound-list;;
    [[(]pattern[ | pattern] ... ) compound-list;;] ...
    [[(]pattern[ | pattern] ... ) compound-list]
esac
```

As I understand, there will be at least one condition in body of `case`, and the `compound-list` corresponded with that condition must be existed.

I wrote a quick test:

```
$ cat test.sh
case $1 in
esac

case $1 in
  .) ;;
  *) echo 1
esac
```

then:

```
$ for shell in /bin/*sh; do
    printf '=%-18s=\n' "$shell"
    "$shell" ./test.sh .
  done
=/bin/ash          =
=/bin/bash         =
=/bin/dash         =
=/bin/heirloom-sh  =
=/bin/ksh          =
=/bin/lksh         =
=/bin/mksh         =
=/bin/pdksh        =
=/bin/posh         =
=/bin/schily-osh   =
=/bin/schily-sh    =
=/bin/sh           =
=/bin/yash         =
=/bin/zsh          =
```

(`/bin/heirloom-sh` is [the Bourne shell from heirloom tool chest](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/sh.html), `/bin/schily-sh and /bin/schily-osh` are [the Schily Bourne shell](http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/bosh.html))

It surprised me! All my known shells accepted the syntax. And also:

```
case $1 in esac
```

work in all shells above but `ksh` (That's `ksh93u+` in my system), although it [worked in `ksh88` as confirmed by schily](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/250839/does-posix-allow-empty-compound-list-in-first-condition-and-empty-condition-in-c?noredirect=1#comment432026_250852).

So is it allowed by POSIX or I missed something?

Comment: When a standard is at variance with every implementation you can think of, it is the specification that is wrong (it happens) or you've misinterpreted it.  Sure, that's a semantic argument of "wrong", but practically, adhering to the spec just won't work.

Comment: Let me add a note: `/opt/schily/bin/osh` is preferred over `/usr/5bin/sh` as it also aims to present a portable version of the OpenSolaris Bourne Shell but includes less bugs that have been introduced from making it portable.

Comment: @schily: Yes, I know. You have noticed me sometimes ago. The order in my test is meaningless.

Comment: BTW: fot those that did not read about the difference before: `/opt/schily/bin/osh` and `/opt/schily/bin/sh` are compiled from the same sources but `osh` only includes the portability changes and some bugfixes for hard problems while `sh` is including a lot of additional code that adds features and that make it behave very close to a POSIX shell. See: http://schilytools.sourceforge.net/bosh.html for a list of new features and features that are still missing for POSIX compliance.

Comment: i always do `${sh##*/}` so i dont have to wind up talking to anybody about my paths.

Answer (score 6):

Here are the grammar rules, if it helps. I'm not great at reading it, but it sure *looks* allowed - for every *pattern + list* case there's also a *pattern + break* case. That third one would seem to indicate you might even go totally *patternless*.  The link is [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_10).

---

```
case_clause      : Case WORD linebreak in linebreak case_list    Esac
                 | Case WORD linebreak in linebreak case_list_ns Esac
                 | Case WORD linebreak in linebreak              Esac
                 ;
case_list_ns     : case_list case_item_ns
                 |           case_item_ns
                 ;
case_list        : case_list case_item
                 |           case_item
                 ;
case_item_ns     :     pattern ')'               linebreak
                 |     pattern ')' compound_list linebreak
                 | '(' pattern ')'               linebreak
                 | '(' pattern ')' compound_list linebreak
                 ;
case_item        :     pattern ')' linebreak     DSEMI linebreak
                 |     pattern ')' compound_list DSEMI linebreak
                 | '(' pattern ')' linebreak     DSEMI linebreak
                 | '(' pattern ')' compound_list DSEMI linebreak
```

---

Anyway - it makes sense to me that it should work. The following works:

```
x=
if $x; then $x; else echo this doesnt happen; fi
```

...because the commands are not empty when parsed and the shell has something to do. I always associate a pattern with an attached list directly. And in fact, they are pretty well conjoined.

```
x=0
for z in a b c d e f g
do    case $z in [abcd]) ;; $((x+=1))) ;; esac
done; echo "$x"
```

---

```
3
```

---

The spec is pretty clear about about the order of expansions and pattern - list associations. I always just naturally conjoin the two and consider them as more or less a single command. And so because the shell *does* something, it can check that box off. It probably has something to do with the way a C switch case works.

Comment: Ah, the grammar make sense that the empty compound-list is allowed. But how about the empty case list? I don't see it in grammar. Your `if` example did not seem to be similar with the empty `case`. The `if` body had at least `$x` for the shell to parse. While the `case` body had nothing.

Comment: @cuonglm - what do you mean? its left out for all of them. and the `if` expands `$x` while parsing just as `case` expands the patterns - each in order and *stopping* at the first match in the same way. a `case` will never expand any patterns beyond a match because the test is passed and the expansion part of the parse is done at that point.

Comment: I mean the parsing occur before expansion. Like when you do `if $x; then ; fi` you got syntax error, `case $x in esac` work well.

Comment: @cuonglm - that's not how it works w/ `case`. not really - it needs the delimiters - but each pattern / list pair is parsed and expanded *together*. once a match is found all of the rest is ignored up to `esac` - as long as *very* special shell chars like `(` and `)` dont interfere with its recognizing `esac`. so if you had list 3 pages long and you matched the first pattern *most* of the time, you'd have a *fast* test anyway.

Comment: Right, I know it but I still confuse about the way shell *parse*. It's interesting that `case $x in esac` work in all my shell test above, except `ksh93`.

Comment: @cuonglm - that is interesting. i just learned that from your question too. i don't really know what good it would do, but i guess it is just the natural consequence of taking the two pieces together. anyway, each list needs a delimiter - so you need `;;` in the right places so the shell can be sure about where `(` `)` are meant to indicate patterns. other than that, it's not parsed much at all until it's expanded.  and when a pattern is expanded the shell can return for the expansion or for the list, you know? which ever comes last. but it doesn't go any further after that.

Comment: @cuonglm - i think i had that wrong - obviously the whole case is parsed out *first* like: *word* in *pattern* ) *not pattern* ;; *pattern* ) *not pattern* ;; *esac* - and i would think thats all the parsing that needs doing.

Comment: It seems that you discovered a bug in `ksh93`.  Note that the case example works without syntax message in `ksh88`.